# No Firebase App has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to run my app and it is giving the following error

*[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()*

I have already called `firebase.initializeApp()` but still the error is same.
here is my code of main file

```
    void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AppointmentsProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Car Wash App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
         
        ),
        home: FutureBuilder(
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
          builder: (ctx, snap) =>
              snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                  ? Center(
                      child: Text('Loading...'),
                    )
                  : StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                      builder: (ctx, snapShot) =>
                          snapShot.hasData ? HomePage() : UserAuth(),
                    ),
        ),
        routes: {
          HomePage.routeName: (_) => HomePage(),
          HistoryPage.routeName: (_) => HistoryPage(),
          MyAppointments.routeName: (_) => MyAppointments(),
          PackagesPage.routeName: (_) => PackagesPage(),
          VehicleType.routeName: (_) => VehicleType(),
          SlotPage.routeName: (_) => SlotPage(),
          ExtraServicesPage.routeName: (_) => ExtraServicesPage(),
          SummaryPage.routeName: (_) => SummaryPage(),
          DetailedScreen.routeName: (_) => DetailedScreen(),
          PaymentMethodScreen.routeName: (_) => PaymentMethodScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did the answer of Baimam Boukar help you?

Comment: it gives this error "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the above answers don't help, you can solve the problem by following steps:

```
delete the project and take backup of lib folder and pubspec.yaml file.
Create a new project with the same name
copy backed up files to the newly created project.
run flutter pub get
you are good to go
```

It literally solved my problem. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 14):

You should initialise it in main().

For example:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

[This link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) might be helpful for you.

EDIT: The first link has been archived. [This is](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web) new way to setup firebase in a Flutter project. Steps are pretty same. Last link contains one more step to configure firebase plugins.

Steps are:

- [Step 1: Install the required command line tools](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#install-cli-tools)
- [Step 2: Configure your apps to use Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#configure-firebase)
- [Step 3: Initialize Firebase in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase)
- [Step 4: Add Firebase plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#add-plugins)

Comment: it is giving this error: Undefined name 'DefaultFirebaseOptions'.

Comment: Hi @AdilNaseem have you followed the documentation steps? first step: `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli` , second step: `flutterfire configure`and this step will create a file named `firebase_options.dart`and you should put it into your project file and call it from main.dart.

Comment: when I try this command in step -1, it gives this error
"'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 4):

Firebase.initializeApp() is an asynchronous function. You should use "await" to ensure Firebase initialization. And use WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() to prevent flutter errors.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem is that you have configure firebase in your flutter project but you have not initialized it before the app starts.

###### You need to initialize the firebase sdk asynchronously. This is how to go about it.

```html
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: it gives this error
"[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized."

Answer (score 2):

This error is know to occur when you fail to add the required dependencies in both your android side of things in project and app level build.gradle files

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your android/build.gradle file.
   Inside dependecies add

   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14' (use latest version)
2. Go to app/build.gradle file.
   Add the plugin outside dependencies

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**1. Install this package**

For installing the Firebase core package [Click here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/install)

In your main.dart:-
    **2. Import Firebase_core package :**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
```

**3. Add these lines in your main :**

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(myApp());
}
```

**It worked for me hoping helpful for others too.**